# Sidebar submenu elements not showing/hiding as they should

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple sidebar for my website using jquery and I am having some trouble with the hover functionality of it. When a user hovers over a category, a submenu is suppose to appear. I would like the submenu to close if a category above or below is hovered. I created a jsFiddle to help show my problem and how submenu doesn't close down like it should. I have been trying to figure this out for hours now, I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/BGcDc/7/

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to hide your subment in the mouseleave function.  Just add `$(this).find(".submenu").hide();` to your existing handler:

```
$(".category").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".submenu").hide();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#eee");
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid grey");
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    $(this).css("width", "180px");
    $(".category:last").css("border-bottom", "1px solid grey");
});
```

Comment: @MHZ if this is what you want than mark this question as correct.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/ahren/BGcDc/8/

Just add a `$(".submenu").hide();` at the start of the hover.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to hide the list

```
$(".category").mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).find(".submenu").hide();

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BGcDc/10/

but this can be acomplished with css only dough.. by:

```
.category .submenu{ display:none}
.category:hover .submenu{ display:block}
```

And of corse all your .css() borders you got there (and makes more sense, it would might make sense if you want to make a cross-browser animation to show/hide)

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your javascript like so:

```
$(".category").mouseleave(function() {
    // add this
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#eee");
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid grey");
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    $(this).css("width", "180px");
    $(".category:last").css("border-bottom", "1px solid grey");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) jQuery method accepts 2 parameters, you can use an anonymous function object in the 2nd parameter to hide the submenu similarly to how you show it in the 1st parameter's function.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/BGcDc/11/)**

The `mouseleave` is also unecessary if you already have a `.hover` listener attached to the elements. This is also simpler and easier to read.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/BGcDc/15/)